# Manage Brands / Manufacturers in admin. Show brand logo and story in Product Page

Tags: magento2, module, attributes, manufacturer

I am looking for a best practice to show **content about** the **manufacturer/brand** on a **product page**. For example brand logo and story/description.

This could be achieved just by importing the description to each product, but it would be a nightmare to manage.
I would like to manage the brands via admin panel or updating an external csv-file.

Is there a "native" way to show more content, based on selected attribute? Or do I need to create a module to get there? All ideas and tips are welcome as I am new to Magento and this forum.

Example image:

[image]

Comment: I found out that there is an extension that does just this called: brand extension for magento 2. I'd recommend this in case someone is struggling with the same thing.